# Magento Payment not working

Tags: magento

I have some problem in payment option.

Whenever I click on continue after shipping the page stays.

I think there are some JS Console errors are there.

Please can someone help me solving this.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/M4BGI

Comment: Check log file for error description and check the payment method configuration which enable in site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

One-page checkout not working after upgrading to 1.9
If you're using the one-page checkout, make sure you have the following javascript in /app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
    //]]>
</script>
```